# Deserialize JSON double array to List or ObservableCollection C# (all the items of all groups)

Tags: arrays

How Deserialize JSON double array to List or ObservableCollection C#? I need all the items of all groups to display in ListView. It's part of the structure of the json string:

```
"Groups": [
  {
     "UniqueId": "Group-1",
     "Title": "",
     "ImagePath": "",
     "ImageAll": "",
     "Color": "",
     "Description": "  ",
     "Items": [
        {
           "UniqueId": "Group-1-Item-1",
           "Title": "",
           "ImagePath": "",
           "Plus": "",
           "Minus": "",
           "Description": "",
           "Prop": "",
           "StepsImgs": "",
           "Content": ""
        },
        {
           "UniqueId": "Group-1-Item-2",
           "Title": "",
           "ImagePath": "",
           "Plus": "",
           "Minus": "",
           "Description": "",
           "Prop": "",
           "StepsImgs": "",
           "Content": ""
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "UniqueId": "Group-2",
     "Title": "",
     "ImagePath": "",
     "ImageAll": "",
     "Color": "",
     "Description": "",
     "Items": [
        {
           "UniqueId": "Group-2-Item-1",
           "Title": "",
           "ImagePath": "",
           "Plus": "",
           "Minus": " ",
           "Description": "",
           "Prop": "",
           "StepsImgs": "",
           "Content": ""
        },
        {
           "UniqueId": "Group-2-Item-2",
           "Title": "",
           "ImagePath": "",
           "Plus": "",
           "Minus": "",
           "Description": "",
           "Prop": "",
           "StepsImgs": "",
           "Content": ""
        }
     ]
  }
]
}
```

using json2csharp.com I received the following:

```
public class Item
   {
      [JsonProperty("UniqueId")]
      public string UniqueId { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("Title")]
      public string Title { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("ImagePath")]
      public string ImagePath { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("Plus")]
      public string Plus { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("Minus")]
      public string Minus { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("Description")]
      public string Description { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("Prop")]
      public string Prop { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("StepsImgs")]
      public string StepsImgs { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("Content")]
      public string Content { get; set; }
   }

   public class Group
   {
      [JsonProperty("UniqueId")]
      public string UniqueId { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("Title")]
      public string Title { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("ImagePath")]
      public string ImagePath { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("ImageAll")]
      public string ImageAll { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("Color")]
      public string Color { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("Description")]
      public string Description { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("Items")]
      public IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
   }

   public class Example
   {
      [JsonProperty("Groups")]
      public IList<Group> Groups { get; set; }
   }
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
  public ObservableCollection<IList<Item>> Example { get; set; }
  public IList<Item> items = new List<Item>();
  public List<MenuItem> MenuItems;

  public MainPage()
  {
     this.InitializeComponent();
     string jS = File.ReadAllText("DataModel/SampleData.json");
     var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Example>>(jS);
     foreach (var itemdetail in result)
     {
        foreach (var itemdetail2 in itemdetail.Groups)
        {
           Example.Add(itemdetail2.Items);
        }
     }
            }
         }
```

The error :

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[UWPУзлы.DataModel.Example]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
```

On line `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Example>>(jS);`

Comment: The variable result should contain all the values, what exactly is your problem? What is expected result and what does go wrong?

Comment: Gives an error message:

Comment: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[UWPУзлы.DataModel.Example]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: in line    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Example>>(jS);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aah, I found it

change this

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Example>>(jS);
```

To this

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(jS);
```

The JSON is an Example object, not array of examples.